# Mods with same prime factorization as base give out same mod as base

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I had a question proposed to me being "Compute $2853^{1429} $(mod $ 2039183)$". Now the answer would be $2853$ by solving a pair of congruences. But that also happens to be the base of the exponent. Now why is this? The prime factorization of $2039183$ is $1429 \cdot 1427$ which is the same as the exponent but is that why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2853^{1429}\equiv2853\bmod1429$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

$2853\equiv-1\bmod1427$, so $2853^{1429}\equiv(-1)^{1429}=-1\equiv2853\bmod1427$.

Therefore, by the constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem,

$2853^{1429}\equiv2853\bmod2039183$.